# How to prevent storing files i haven't imported\pinned into my node?

Tags: storage, datastore, ipfs

I have just installed an IPFS Desktop app on my computer for the first time ever, gone to `Files` sectoion and removed all 2 pinned files that were there. I didn't even get why something was pinned by default right after installation.

Then, I just started to watch what would happen. After a few minutes I've started to see spikes in network bandwidth as well as an amount of blocks and storage size started to increase.

So, the questions are:

1. If I haven't even imported\pinned any file yet, why the storage is started to fill? I guess it was filling with someones files.
2. How can I prevent it and "seed" only files\data I manually add to my IPFS node?

I'd like to just "seed" my files in read-only mode and prevent constant writes and wearing out my SSD as well as exclude unneeded network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IPFS caches things you access by default.

That cache is cleared during "garbage collection", which happens by default once every hour.

2. You can change this default behavior:

- reprovider/strategy "pinned" https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/configure-node/#reprovider
- routing.type "dhtclient" https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/configure-node/#routing

Comment: From the docs you're referring to:`Reprovider.Strategy ... Tells reprovider what should be announced. ... "pinned" - only announce pinned data` For me it means that a node won't just _announce_ about some files it stores. But it still shouldn't prevent it from actually storing them, should it?

Comment: correct, the reprovider setting doesn't stop ipfs from caching files you access (until the next garbage collection), it just stops it from announcing those files to other peers that want to download it. That should solve your second question.